# Embed SQL Server database inside a C# application

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to create a standalone desktop application in C#, that must be linked to a SQL Server database. 
The app must work without internet connection, hence I need to somehow embed the database inside the .exe file.
Entity Framework and lazy loading must work as well.
How can I obtain that?

Comment: You don't. The closest you can get is to use sqlexpress.

Comment: hence I should force the users to install sqlserver express alongside my app (eg. including it in the installer), such that each user will have his local db with the same data, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't can be achieve using Code First EF with the package is already installed?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I don't think I deeply understood what you were thinking about... Are you suggesting an initial overhead to build a local db with EFCodeFirst at the first boot? The point is that my app should reference an already existing remote db, and it should do it OFFLINE, hence the best idea I had was to somehow "download" that db and embed it inside my app.

Answer (score 0):

Is SQL server on same computer? If so, take a look at this
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36895/Building-an-embedded-database-engine-in-C

If not, just use in C# System.Data.SQlClient;
SQL client is on every Win machine pre-installed